# create function to format a column in a dataframe

Tags: r, function, dplyr

I have a date time that I'm trying to strip and clean. I'm not sure if there is something out of the box for this. I've done some searching but couldn't find anything.  The date format is..

```
2017-01-01T01:36:17.000Z
```

reproducible example:

```
StartDate <- c("2017-01-01T01:36:17.000Z", "2017-01-01T01:36:17.000Z")
Num <- c(1,2)
DataFrame <- data_frame(Num, StartDate)
```

I've fixed it by doing the following

```
require(dplyr)
require(tidyr)
require(lubridate)

DataFrame <- DataFrame %>%
   separate(StartDate , into = c("NewDate", "tail"), sep = "T") %>%
   mutate(NewDate= ymd(NewDate)) %>%
   select(-tail)
```

What I would like to do is to turn it into a function so that I can just pipe it when I need to.

I came up with the following, but haven't been able to get it to work. I've also tried variations of separate_, and mutate_. But still no luck.

```
ztime <- function(df, datecol, newcol) {
  library(lubridate)
  library(tidyr)
  library(dplyr)


  df <- df %>%
    separate_(datecol, into = c(newcol, "extra"), sep = "T") #%>%
    mutate_(newcol = ymd(newcol)) %>%
    select(-extra)

}
```

Hoping for some insight! Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you call `as_date` from lubridate ?

```
dater <- function(x){
  lubridate::as_date(x)
}
dater("2017-01-01T01:36:17.000Z")
[1] "2017-01-01"
```

Best

Colin

Comment: perfect. I guess I didn't know about as_date. This is perfect, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

There's a game changing package for that! `anytime`

```
library(anytime)

NewDataFrame <- DataFrame %>% 
  mutate(NewDate = anytime(StartDate))
```

I'm always amazed at how much it cleans up and interprets

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use

```
ztime <- function(df, datecol, newcol) {
  df[[newcol]] <- lubridate::ymd_hms(df[[datecol]])
}
```